# Java: random number is the same for everything

Tags: java, arrays, random

```
import java.util.Random;

class Moo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.println("Index\tValue");
        int randnumb = 1 + rand.nextInt(11);
        int array[] = new int[5];

        array[0] = randnumb;
        array[1] = randnumb;
        array[2] = randnumb;
        array[3] = randnumb;
        array[4] = randnumb;

        for (int counter=0; counter < array.length; counter++)
            System.out.println(counter + "\t" + array[counter]);
    }

}
```

**The problem**: every element has the same value, but I want every element to have random and different values.

Comment: The questions place is not here.

Comment: You need to loop through the array and assign a random value evrytime

Comment: You assigned the same number to every element so they are the same.

Answer (score 7):

thats because you've assigned same value

```
array[0]=randnumb;
array[1]=randnumb;
array[2]=randnumb;
array[3]=randnumb;
array[4]=randnumb;
```

You need to do

```
array[0]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
array[1]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
array[2]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
array[3]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
array[4]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
```

Or you can do it in a better way

```
Random randomNum = new Random();
int[] arr = new int[5];

/*Iterate through the loop for array length and populate
  and assign random values for each of array element*/

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = randomNum.nextInt(11);
}
```

and you can access those values using

```
for (int i : arr) {
     // do whatever you want with your values here.I'll just print them
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `nextInt()` each time you want a new random number to be generated. So do something like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();

System.out.println("Index\tValue");
// Don't need this anymore...
//int randnumb = 1+rand.nextInt(11);
int array[]= new int[5];

array[0]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
array[1]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
array[2]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
array[3]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
array[4]=1+rand.nextInt(11);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning randnumb a value and using the same value to initialize you array elements. Try this.

```
import java.util.Random;

class moo{
public static void main(String[] args){

Random rand = new Random();

System.out.println("Index\tValue");
int randnumb; 
int array[]= new int[5];
for(int j=0;j<=4;j++)
{
    randnumb=1+rand.nextInt(11);
    array[j]=randnumb;
}

for(int counter=0;counter<array.length;counter++)
        System.out.println(counter +"\t"+array[counter]);

}
```

}